# VB.NET array of objects slows down when filling

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance

I have a problem in VB.NET. I have an array of a custom object, "ITNObject", which has two elements to it, a sting and an int.

The code loops over a set of XML files, reading the nodes, then adding to the master array. The aim is to then output the array to a MySQL table.

Now, the important bit. When I write the array at the end of each loop (once per file), the performance is linear.

However, if I fill an array for all files, and write it once at the end, the application gets progressively slower as the array fills.

There are several million objects in the array at the end.

Any suggestions? The code below shows the part where the array is filled, this code is called for each file. In this example it is filling for the entire set of files.

The slow down is significant, each file starts off by taking about 15 ms, after a few hundred loops (approx 100,000 ITNObjects in array) it slows to approximately 600 ms per file.

How can I fix this?

```
Public Sub ReadITN(filetoDecompress As String)

    Dim XDoc As Xml.XmlDocument
    XDoc = New Xml.XmlDocument
    XDoc.Load(filetoDecompress)
    Dim nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(XDoc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("os", "http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/namespaces/osgb")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RoadRank As Integer
    Dim toid() As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim descNode As XmlNode
    Dim xmlNodes As XmlNodeList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//os:RoadLink", nsmgr)
    Dim loopCount As Integer = 0
    For Each mxmlnode As XmlNode In xmlNodes 'XDoc.GetElementsByTagName("osgb:RoadLink")
        x = 0
        ReDim Preserve toid(x)

        For Each n As XmlNode In mxmlnode.SelectNodes(".//os:referenceToTopographicArea", nsmgr)
            'If n.Name = "osgb:referenceToTopographicArea" Then
            ReDim Preserve toid(x)
            toid(x) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(n.Attributes.Item(0).Value, Len(n.Attributes.Item(0).Value) - 1)
            x = x + 1
            'End If
        Next n

        descNode = mxmlnode.SelectSingleNode(".//os:descriptiveTerm", nsmgr)

        RoadRank = 0
        Select Case UCase(descNode.InnerText)
            Case "MOTORWAY" : RoadRank = 1
            Case "A ROAD" : RoadRank = 2
            Case "B ROAD" : RoadRank = 3
            Case "MINOR ROAD" : RoadRank = 4
            Case "LOCAL STREET" : RoadRank = 5
            Case "PRIVATE ROAD" : RoadRank = 6
            Case "PRIVATE ROAD - RESTRICTED ACCESS" : RoadRank = 7
            Case "PRIVATE ROAD - PUBLICLY ACCESSIBLE" : RoadRank = 8
            Case "PEDESTRIANISED STREET" : RoadRank = 9
            Case "ALLEY" : RoadRank = 10
        End Select

        If toid(0) <> "" Then

            For i = 0 To x - 1
                ReDim Preserve ITNObjects(ITNCount)
                If ITNObjects(ITNCount) Is Nothing Then
                    ITNObjects(ITNCount) = New ITNObject()
                End If

                ITNObjects(ITNCount).Toid = toid(i)
                ITNObjects(ITNCount).RoadRank = RoadRank
                ITNCount = ITNCount + 1
            Next i
        End If
        Erase toid
    Next

    descNode = Nothing
    xmlNodes = Nothing
    XDoc = Nothing
    toid = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `List(Of T)` instead of an array? You're "ReDim"ming the array on every addition, no wonder it takes linear time to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list instead of an array.

In .NET you can't resize an array. The `ReDim Preserve` command creates a new array, and copies all items from the old array to the new array. This will naturally take longer the larger the array is.

Create the list:

```
Dim ITNObjects as New List(Of ITNObject)
```

Add an item to the list:

```
Dim temp as New ITNObject()
temp.Toid = toid(i)
temp.RoadRank = RoadRank
ITNObjects.Add(temp)
```

Comment: of course!  That seems to do the job perfectly.  Many thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 2):

```
  ReDim Preserve toid(x)
```

You've written an O(n^2) algorithm.  Every time you add a new element to the array, you are creating a *new* array that needs to copy all of the old elements.  O(n^2) algorithms behave poorly for large values of n, as you found out.

You solve this with a so-called *exponential back-off* allocation strategy.  The principle is simple, you just double the size of the array when it becomes full.  Like this:

```
 If toid.GetUpperBound(0) < x Then ReDim Preserve toid(2 * x)
```

Which is the exact same strategy used by the .NET collection classes.  Like List(Of T), the better array type.

Comment: It has a name: [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)